# Method to work with class and file attributes

Tags: vb.net, oop

I'm quite new to using classes and i'm doing some job in Visual Basic Express 2010.
I have a some thougts about to how to proceed with my project. The application will go thru the open files in a CAD software (SolidWorks 2012) and check the file attributes and the equations in the CAD file. This is done using API functions.

I started off using a DataGridView as object in order to add the open files and then I ran another function to check and give them status if update is needed or not. Now I have faced that using a DataGridView was not the best... since I would also like to use the code without the DataGridView.

So, now I'm aiming to start using classes. Thinking of setting up a class for the files that are open and have properties that contains what was previously stored in the DataGridView. Using the class I thinking of would look something like this:

```
swCADfile.Path = "C:\A.sldprt"
swCADfile.swAttribute1.Name = "ApprovedDate"
swCADfile.swAttribute1.DataType = ... 'Function to get DataType if attribute
swCADfile.swAttribute1.Status ="OK" 'Function to set OK / NOT OK depening on DataType
swCADfile.swAttribute1.StatusMessage = "" 'Message depending on if attribute is missing or wrong DataType

swCADfile.swAttribute2.. etc etc
```

By using this class I will then add each open file to a list which later can be processed for the purpuse of update and recheck if the triggered change had impact.

My question is what you guys think of this set up. The number of attributes and equations is limited to a total of six. Therefore I currently think of making each attribute as a property and not as list within the property....

Please let me know if my thoughts is in the right direction or advise how I should use classes in the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make the attributes a list, just for flexibility. If ever you get more attributes to add, think of the amount of changes you will have to make in your entire program to accommodate. A list would give you flexibility for the future.

By the way, making classes for your objects is the right way to go. I don't quite understand the thing with the DataGridView though. The DGV is a UI element and should have nothing to do with your decision to make classes or not. If you want to present data to your users the DGV is a perfectly valid way of doing it.

I would go for a panel that displays the file attributes, combined with a ListBox to select the file for which attributes are displayed, but to each his own.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will go for a list. Agree with the ease when adding more attributes in the future.